# MultiDimensional array in Laravel with an ID outside the array

Tags: laravel

How can i save a multidimensional array with a booking_id outside the array

```
array:2 [
  "issues" => array:2 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "issue" => "Skin Allergies/Irritation"
      "url" => "1615955206.jpg"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "issue" => "Diabetes/Hypertension/Asthma"
      "url" => "1615957750.jpg"
    ]
  ]
  "booking_id" => 722955
]
```

what i want is when im saving every issue, it will also save the relationship of booking_id
i have this controller

**MobileBookingController**

```
public function MobileBookingIssue(Request $request)
{
   
    $data[]=$request->all();
    $courseData=[];
    foreach($data as $d){
        $courseData[]= [
          'booking_id'=> $d->booking_id,
          'issue'=> $d['issue'],
          'url'=> $d['url'],
       ];

    };
     DB::table("booking_health_issues")->insert("courseData");
     return response()->json(["message" => "success"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use from `$request->booking_id` instead of `$d->booking_id`.

```
public function MobileBookingIssue(Request $request)
{

   $data[]=$request->all();
   $courseData=[];
   $tst = $this->input->post('issues');
   for($i=0; $i < count($tst); $i++){
       $courseData[]= [
         'booking_id'=> $request->booking_id,
         'issue'=>  $this->input->post('issue')[$i],
         'url'=> $this->input->post('url')[$i],
      ];

   };
    DB::table("booking_health_issues")->insert("courseData");
    return response()->json(["message" => "success"]);
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering, I still have an error of Undefined index: issue

Comment: Sorry May I know if i can achieve this without using Input ?

Comment: @dacdac you can use ``$request->get('issue')[$i]``, So why you don't want to use from ``input``?

Comment: for more go here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests

Comment: Nothing in particular . i just want to have a multiple option . but thanks for helping its now solved . thanks alot

Comment: Hello again Bro. may ask a new question im really stuck at this . the error is "Undefined property: App\\Http\\Controllers\\Bookings\\BranchAppointment::$input",

Comment: import this at the top of your controller ``use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;``

Answer (score 0):

try this

```php
public function MobileBookingIssue(Request $request)
{

    $data[] = $request->all();
    $courseData = [];
    foreach ($data as $d) {
        $courseData['issues'][] = [
            'issue' => $d['issue'],
            'url' => $d['url'],
        ];
        $courseData['booking_id'] = $request->booking_id;
    };
   

    DB::table("booking_health_issues")->insert($courseData);
    return response()->json(["message" => "success"]);
}
```

this code will generate array like this

```php
array:2 [
  "issues" => array:2 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "issue" => "Skin Allergies/Irritation"
      "url" => "1615955206.jpg"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "issue" => "Diabetes/Hypertension/Asthma"
      "url" => "1615957750.jpg"
    ]
  ]
  "booking_id" => 722955
]
```

Comment: thanks for answering .  im having an error of Undefined index: issue,

Comment: How you can get ``booking_id`` outside of ``loop`` using ``$d``?

Comment: @dacdac sorry i did'nt notice that now you can check but it will take last loop's `book_id`